# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object while starting Spyder 5.2.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, typeerror, spyder

I created a new environment in conda with Spyder 5.2.2 and Python 3.10.2. Now, I'm experiencing an error telling me that the program expects a string or byte-like object while starting the Spyder. Interestingly, this does not happen when my Python is 3.9.* . Any reason this can happen?

Here is the error encountered:

```
(py10) PS C:\Users\Kevin Yew> spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 233, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 41, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 47, in check_qt
    if parse_version(actual_ver) < parse_version(required_ver):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 120, in parse_version
    return packaging.version.Version(v)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 264, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

**Edit**
Here's the code you can try to reproduce the error.

```
conda create -n py10 python=3.10.2
conda activate py10
conda install spyder
spyder
```

Comment: Can you share the sample code which you ran along with the above error log ?

Comment: @Alonso I have added it above my error, I was using Anaconda command prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is an error in the code that checks if PyQt5 is present and it will be fixed in our next version (5.3.0) to be released in March 2022 (see [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/17402)).

Answer (score 1):

I have glanced through the posts about the issues in Spyder and apparently, it involves upgrading or downgrading certain packages to solve the problem of running Spyder. When I look into the updatable packages in Anaconda Navigator, the PyQt and Qt are not in the latest release. I tried my luck to update it to the latest version and now the Spyder works! Now I can run my Spyder with Python 3.10.2 :-)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this running:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyqt
```